# MessageBox() in Powerbuilder taking longer time than expected

Tags: messagebox, powerbuilder

I was checking our system for performance issue and found out that messagebox() takes relatively longer time. I am not sure what is causing this to take more time. Does anyone have any idea about it?

Is there an alternative to messagebox?
Appeon version - 2017
OS Version - Windows 2016.

Comment: relative to what?

Comment: for 3 hits it took 10sec as total time to execute, which i think is a lot.

Comment: Can you edit your question, and include the code that you used to arrive at the 10-sec total time?

Comment: i did not use any code. i ran profiling to check teh system performance and saw that a function took huge amount of time. When i traced in down further i found that messageBox actually took the most time. I am not sure if i can attach a SS here to show exactly what i could see.

Comment: Well, a MessageBox() requires *some kind* of user-interaction.  Could it be that the 10-sec is a result of just that?  IOW, the duration of the MessageBox() call will be from the time it is invoked in code, to the time the message is acknowledged by the user...